# IPYTHON code using numpy arrays and %pylab inline

Tags: python, numpy, ipython

I have code written for `IPython Notebook`. At the top it says `%pylab inline`.
The code uses `numpy` and `np`. I am trying to make a project using this code in `PyCharm` but it fails to run. I put `import numpy` at the top but the lines that use `np` fail . It says `global name 'np' not defined`.

I've determined that the line `%pylab inline` has something to do with it. Is there an import I can use that will define `np` or is this only an `IPython` thing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When transferring the code from `IPython` to `PyCharm`,
replace `%pylab inline` with the following code:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pylab, mlab, pyplot
np = numpy
plt = pyplot

from IPython.core.pylabtools import figsize, getfigs

from pylab import *
from numpy import *
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `import numpy as np` instead of `import numpy`.

Using the prefix `numpy` can be quite cumbersome. Therefore the `numpy` module is usually imported with the shorter module name `np`.

These two code snippets do the same:

```
import numpy
numpy.sqrt(3*3 + 4*4)
```

Here as an alias:

```
import numpy as np
np.sqrt(3*3 + 4*4)
```

For larger programs the aliased version is much cleaner and therefore `import numpy as np` can be considered a standard now.

Comment: Forgot to mention I already tried that and my program crashes in PyCharm . So it seems to me np works differently than numpy ? What does %pylab inline do ? The IPython code uses both "numpy" and "np" . In PyCharm when I change the np references to numpy , or vice versa , it crashes . Why would it do that ?

Comment: `%pylab` chooses the necessary backend for inline graphics and does quite a number of imports for you. Note, that it is now deprecated. That said, without knowing seeing the notebook I can only guess what's the issue here.